# Trigger storyboard on Button click?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

When I try to start my app with this code it throws an exception saying error text cannot be found.

```
<Button>
<Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:05"
                            To="1" From="0"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentGrid"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>

        </Button.Triggers>
 </Button>
```

Seems like something wrong with the routed event property. What will fix this exception.

Comment: I had left one comment, then realized I didn't pay attention. That way of doing it like you're used to in WPF isn't accepted in UWP. You'll either need to do interaction triggers or just do a quick Storyboard.Begin() method to call it via Click="MethodName" on the button with a one liner of codebehind. If I wasn't in a rush I'd pop you an example but I'm sure someone will read this and grab the points. :)

Comment: I was hoping for no code behind lol. I'm trying to do interaction triggers but I haven't figured out how to add a story board to it. it complains when I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way is to use a Behavior. It's their purpose to extend the functions of basic controls combined with reusability. You can see a snippet right over here on [Windows blog](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/30/xaml-behaviors-open-source-and-on-uwp/) (and as I see, it's [a part of the framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xaml.interactions.core.eventtriggerbehavior(v=vs.120).aspx) in Namespace: **Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core** Assembly: **Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions** in Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.dll).

```
<Button x:Name="button">
   <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
         <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="storyboard1"/>
      </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
   </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```